# How to switch or assume role from Visual Studio to access AWS resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, visual-studio

I've a standard user account with programmatic access in AWS and whenever I want to work with resources then I need to switch role in AWS console and works all good. Now that I want to achieve the same from Visual Studio, how do I do that? I have created a profile and I've ensured that I've all the necessary access also followed AWS instructions at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-visual-studio/latest/user-guide/credentials.html I'm still getting 'Access Denied' message.

Comment: I would check CloudTrail logs for the corresponding user/role being used in the account between which method you are using IAM Role or credentials and how you have configured that via shared credentials file or via SDK Credential Store?

Comment: Anirudha - is there any way to do this. can you post your solution as an answer?

Comment: @GauravUpadhyay Unfortunately not, didn't find any solution to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution worked for me and I am posting this answer for the community.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-visual-studio/latest/user-guide/mfa-credentials.html

I needed to add a profile entry in the .credentials file located  C:\Users\USERNAME\.aws\credentials. in windows using this example.

```
[toolkit-user]
aws_access_key_id = AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE ( your aws programatic access key )
aws_secret_access_key = wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY (your aws programatic secret key)

[mfa]
source_profile = toolkit-user
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::111111111111:role/toolkit-role    ( ARN of the 
AWS IAM Role  -  this is the account where you want to switch role)
mfa_serial = arn:aws:iam::111111111111:mfa/toolkit-user   ( ARN of the AWS IAM User of standard user )
```

Then in visual studio AWS connection choose this MFA profile to switch roles.
additional entries can be added for multiple accounts.

**There are two profiles defined in the example provided:**

**[toolkit-user]** profile includes the access key and secret access key that were generated and saved when you created the IAM user in Step 2.

**[mfa]** profile defines how multi-factor authentication is supported.

**There are three entries:**

- **source_profile**: Specifies the profile whose credentials are used to assume the role specified by this role_arn setting in this profile. In this case, it's the toolkit-user profile.
- **role_arn**: Specifies the Amazon Resource Name (ARN) of the IAM role that you want to use to perform operations requested using this profile. In this case, it's the ARN for the role you created in Step 1.
- **mfa_serial**: Specifies the identification or serial number of the MFA device that the user must use when assuming a role. In this case, it's the ARN of the virtual device you set up in Step 3.

Comment: Hey @Gaurav, even after adding the profiles, the AWS Explorer in VS does not show the profiles. Where do you see the new profiles?

Comment: @VinitDivekar - It shows in aws explorer. there is 1 drop down labelled as credentials. you will find all your profiles in dropdown.